# Calculating mean confidence intervals from a sample with low SEM

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, standard-deviation, standard-error, central-limit-theorem

**Given that:**

- **I.** The distribution of means of large enough samples converge to a normal distribution (by CLT).
- **II.** The Standard Error of the Mean (SEM) of a sample approaches the Standard Deviation (SD) of the means as the sample size increases (also, SEM is low for larger samples).

Does that mean that if the SEM of a single sample **is low** I can assume there is 95% prob of the pop mean to be nearly between sample mean +- 1.96*SEM ?

**Rational behind the question**:

- A random sample ${z}$ of largely enough size ${n}$ selected out of a population ${p}$ has a **SEM** of $\dfrac{std({z})}{\sqrt[2]{n}}$
- Suppose **SEM** is very low, thus mean(${z}$) approaches mean(${p}$)
- Let ${c}$ be a set constituted by the **means** of enough samples of size ${n}$ taken from ${p}$; thus ${c}$ is normally distributed (**I.**)
- Remember that for a large enough sample **SEM** approaches ${std(c)}$ (**II.**)
- Since as stated by CLT mean(${c}$) also approaches mean(${p}$), and mean(${p}$) is close to mean(${z}$) (low SEM) can we assume that there is approximately 95% probability that ${mean(p)}$ is equal to ${mean(z) +/- SEM*1.96}$ ?

**E.g:** [Python dice simulation](https://github.com/GabrielBarberini/CS-EE-HQEM/blob/master/6-00sc/FingerExercises/random/central_limit_theorem.py)

Relates to [Calculating the confidence interval for the mean value from a sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541536/calculating-the-confidence-interval-for-the-mean-value-from-a-sample)

**Disclaimer:**
It is my first post in this forum so I deeply appreciate any feedback that might improve the quality of my next questions.

Comment: Is the second point true? The standard error of the mean in a sample of size $n$ is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ where $\sigma$ is the population standard deviation.

Comment: Is  for SEM the population SD or the sample SD? 
I'm calculating SEM with the standard deviation of the sample (at least this is what John Guttag does in [his book](https://www.amazon.com.br/Introduction-Computation-Programming-Using-Python/dp/0262542366/ref=pd_lpo_1?pd_rd_i=0262542366&psc=1) ) and assuming it approaches the standard deviation of the means (--> normal by CLT)

Comment: Your notation doesn't help to understand difficult concepts... A good place to start is the definition of a confidence interval. The correct interpretation of a 95% CI is not that there is 95% probability that the population parameter is inside the interval. But that if we were to repeat the same experiment/simulation many times, 95% of the CIs we construct will contain the population parameter.

Comment: To be fully honest I'm having difficulties to understand the difference between that and a probability. I'll look for some stat book to make sure I grasp the concepts the right way. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: It's not the most intuitive concept. One specific CI (such as sample_mean $\pm$ 1.96*SEM) either contains or doesn't contain the population mean (this is a *yes* or *no* event). When you have many CIs, you can think of the proportion of *yes* events as a probability. I like the explanation in this free online book: [Improving Your Statistical Inferences](https://lakens.github.io/statistical_inferences/confint.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll have a look